# Password protect files before emailing

Tags: email, html5, password-protection

I have a HTML5 folder with an HTML file and also a media folder which the HTML doc reads. I want to be able to protect the media folder before emailing, but of course the HTML doc still needs access to it to show the page (locally). I don't need a form of password protection (unless it is necessary); I just want to lock access to the media folder so that it cannot be opened or edited on the end users machine (Windows, Mac)

Any ideas?

Thanks, and again, I apologise if this is in the wrong place.

Comment: Essentially, you're asking about setting up copy protection.  In the digital world, it's impossible to (permanently) keep somebody from copying something you give them; among other things, in order to play any media, you have to open it.  In the case of something like an image file, there's not anything you can do; remember browsers have that nifty `Save image as...` dialog.  You _could_ put some sort of watermark on it, although those can be removed...

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. Without read access to the media folder, the content cannot be displayed at all. There is no way to allow reading and also prevent the data from being copied, edited etc. If the files can be read, the data is fully in the end user's control, because he owns the hardware that stores and processes the content.

The only way to ensure your data cannot be altered or copied, is to not send it (in a readable state). The html document will not be able to read it either.